# How to turn a json string with lists containing different type into a Java object

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "asks": [
        [
            "348.99999998",
            77.078
        ],
        [
            "348.99999999",
            3.12491851
        ]
    ],
    "bids": [
        [
            "348.14449745",
            12.40122304
        ],
        [
            "348.14449743",
            15.00073379
        ]
    ],
    "isFrozen": "0",
    "seq": 187353727
}
```

This is the string and similar stuff can be got from [here](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=USDT_ETH&depth=2)

I wrote the following class for Gson but it is making Gson crash.

```
class PoloniexOrderBook {
    ArrayList<Map<String, Double>> bids;
    ArrayList<Map<String, Double>> asks;
    String isFrozen;
    int seq;


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `[[...],[...]]` is a list of lists, not a list of maps.  Using a `Map` isn't going to work at all, I think.

Comment: Make it a `List<List<Object>> asks;` or make a custom parser

Comment: I tried Googling for "GSON list of heterogeneous objects".  Maybe [this link](https://codexample.org/questions/346775/defining-class-for-gson-with-heterogeneous-list-of-string-and-integers.c) has something useful?

Answer (score 1):

Your fields should be like this:

```
@SerializedName("asks")
private List<List<String>> asks = null;
@SerializedName("bids")
private List<List<String>> bids = null;
@SerializedName("isFrozen")
private String isFrozen;
@SerializedName("seq")
private Integer seq;
```

Use [this page](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert from `JSON` to `POJO` class.

Answer (score -1):

Approach:

JSON:{"asks":[["349.98000000",70.83367131],["349.98021035",14.97213758]],"bids":[["349.91166666",0.00090881],["349.90000000",2.5207202]],"isFrozen":"0","seq":187351414}

POJO Class should be like this for JSON given above

```
class PoloniexOrderBook {
      @JsonProperty("asks")
      private List<List<Object>> asks = null;
      @JsonProperty("bids")
      private List<List<Object>> bids = null;
      @JsonProperty("isFrozen")
      private String isFrozen;
      @JsonProperty("seq")
      private Integer seq;
  }
```

Optional:

Create JSON as below, so that it wont create any problem POJO Class you created

{"asks":[{"349.98000000":70.83367131,"349.98021035":14.97213758}],"bids":[{"349.91166666":0.00090881,"349.90000000":2.5207202}],"isFrozen":"0","seq":187351414}

POJO Class:

```
class PoloniexOrderBook {
ArrayList<Map<String, Double>> bids;
ArrayList<Map<String, Double>> asks;
String isFrozen;
int seq;
```

}

Comment: Are you suggesting that he hack into someone else's server and rewrite their code to return better JSON?

Comment: No, In-order to make POJO class work, i suggested to use above JSON

Comment: How do you suggest he "use" (or "create") the above JSON?  The problem seems to be that he's using a web site, and the web site returns JSON in the format he put in his question.  He can't change that.  He's not writing his own JSON, the server is doing that.  So how do you suggest he "use" the JSON you suggest?  If you suggest he write a translator that converts from the original format to the format you're suggesting, please provide information on the best way to do that.